# Questions on marriage DAY of Shiva and Sati

Tags: shiva, marriage, shiva-purana, parvati, sati-goddess

Shiva married divine mother twice, once when She was incarnated as Sati and another when she was incarnated as Parvati. Mahashivaratri is popularly known for Shiva-Parvati marriage. Was both marriage days same which we celebrate as Mahashivaratri ? If not,which day Shiva married Sati? Do we celebrate this day as one of the auspicious day like Mahashivaratri too?

Answer (score 4):

#### As per the description of the Śiva Purana, it doesn't seem to be on the Maha-Śivaratri which is famously observed in the Magha.

[Chapter 18](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226038.html) - Marriage of Śiva and Satī, Section 2.2 - Rudra-saṃhitā (2): Satī-khaṇḍa, Śiva Purana

> 20. **In the bright half of the month of Caitra (March-April) on the thirteenth day when the star was Uttarā Phalguni on a Sunday, lord
>     Śiva started.**
> 21. Going ahead, with all the devas, led by Brahmā and Viṣṇu and accompanied by the sages, Śiva shone brilliantly.
> 22. Great festivities were arranged by Devas and the attendants of Śiva who were in the happiest mood, on their way.
> 23. The hides of elephant and tiger, the serpents, the crescent moon and the matted hair, all became fitting ornaments and embellishments
>     at Śiva’s will.
> 24. Then in a trice, Śiva reached Dakṣa’s abode seated on his speedy bull and along with Viṣṇu and others.
> 25. With great humility and boundless joy, Dakṣa along with his people welcomed Him.
> 26. The Devas and their attendants were honoured by Dakṣa. The sages were seated in their due order.
> 27. Then Dakṣa took Śiva within the house along with the devas and the sages.
> 28. The delighted Dakṣa worshipped lord Śiva, after offering him an excellent seat.
> 29. He worshipped Viṣṇu, me, the brahmins, devas and the Gaṇas of Śiva, with great devotion and in a fitting manner.
> 30. After performing the suitable worship, Dakṣa in the presence of respectable sages announced the marriage agreement.
> 31. Then Dakṣa, my son, knelt before me, his father, with pleasure and said—“O lord, the marriage rites shall be performed by you.”
> 32. Saying ‘Amen’ I got up with a delightful heart and performed the preliminary rites.
> 33. Then in an auspicious conjunction of stars with the planets in a propitious position, Dakṣa joyfully gave his daughter Satī to Siva.
> 34. **As a part of the rites of marriage the delighted Śiva grasped the hand of Satī of comely appearance.**
>
> English Translation by J.L. Shastri

---

- So, while the Maha-Shivratri is observed on the 14th day of the Krishna Paksha in the Magha or Phalguna Month (varying as per the *amanta* used), the marriage of Shiva & Sati was performed in the Chaitra Month, as per the Shiva Purana.
- And, The only known festival or vrata, according to me, which is followed on a trayodashi of every month is the bi-monthly Pradosha Vrata. (cf. Agni Purana [Ch. 191](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-agni-purana/d/doc1083420.html))

Comment: One more question is left: " Do we celebrate this day as one of the auspicious day like Mahashivaratri too?"

Comment: Not a major festival, but I think it's a part of the bi-monthly Pradosh Vrata. @TheLittleNaruto